# How do I enable hlint for haskell linting?

Tags: haskell-mode

I am trying to select `hlint` and use it as the default for `haskell-mode`. I recall accidentally finding the option for this once, but haven't been able to find it again. 
I am new to Emacs and do not know what to look for.

Comment: Have a search in this SE as well as on SO, for example: [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19454/17548) , You will need to configure haskell-mode requirements and hooks in your init file, so be prepared to learn how the init file works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the option under <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> `flycheck-select-checker` `haskell-hlint`.

I could not find how to set haskell-hlint directly, so I instead disabled ghc and stack ghc from flycheck in my init, which causes flycheck to use hlint.

```
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(haskell-ghc haskell-stack-ghc))
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to directly state hlint as my preferred default.

Comment: Customizable variable `haskell-check-command` is set to hlint by default here by haskell-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I've just added support for hlint in Attrap.

https://github.com/jyp/attrap#configuration-of-the-hlint-checker